# migrating wordpress plugin from php 5 to 7

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, php-7

We've been using a Wordpress plugin called abase, to create on-the-fly forms and access MySQL tables directly. It's very easy to use for both the developer (minimal pseudo coding) and to the end-user. We'd very much like to keep using it in the long run, since it solves all our problems. But there is an issue. The developer no longer supports it and is stuck in PHP 5 code. So if I bring PHP to any version of 7, it breaks completely.

My IT headquarters require all servers to be on 7.3 or higher since there are security vulnerabilities with PHP 5.

Right now I have these options:

1. Try to find a way to migrate the script, although I think it'll be very difficult since the original developer is not available. I'm far from a PHP expert
2. Look for a replacement script, although I've done that already and haven't found a suitable script yet
3. Since is a server that is not pointing to the outside, maybe talk with IT and ask them to let me run PHP 5 on this server

So, what would you recommend? Are you aware of a similar plugin or maybe a script that I can use to replace it?

This is the plugin source: https://github.com/wp-plugins/abase

Comment: I'd discard option 3, PHP 5 is no longer being officially supported and you'll still have to migrate to PHP 7 at some point. Postponing the upgrade just because of a single plugin that doesn't seem critical for the operation of your website doesn't seem reasonable.

Comment: It is a small Plugin(3 files); you can rent some Developer/Freelancer to convert it ..